# Resetting font size shortcut for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I love working with Sublime Text, but one of its features annoys me sometimes which is `"the accidental zoom in"`. Whenever that happens it breaks the momentum and I have to change it back to where it was and is kind of annoying. I searched for a shortcut which can reset the size back to normal but each one of them involved creating a python file and it does not work for me for some reason.

What would made my life much easier that if I could just change something in `Preference.sublime-settings` file and reset the font back to where I wanted it to be with just a shortcut key say `"Control+0"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "accidental zoom in"? Accidentally scrolling with the mouse wheel while control is pressed?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant or in my case accidental press of trackpad while pressing Control key.!

Comment: Add the keyboard binding shown here: https://coderwall.com/p/nvz-ra/resetting-sublime-text-s-zoom-font-size-via-keyboard

Comment: I am stuck in zoomed in hell and now Sublime Text is unusable. What is my quickest way out? In the meantime, I have to install another text editor to be able to do my work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For background, Sublime Text 3 has commands named `increase_font_size` and `decrease_font_size`. These commands modify the font size up or down by some value (depending on what it is currently set to) and then directly modify the setting in the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, which makes the change permanent everywhere.

These commands are bound by default to <kbd>Ctrl+WheelUp/Down</kbd> as well as <kbd>Ctrl++</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+-</kbd>.

There exists a command `reset_font_size` (not bound to a key by default), but this command works by erasing the font size setting entirely; thus if you weren't using the default font size, this is unlikely to be useful. Additionally, this would also not reset any e.g. syntax specific font size.

There is a `set_setting` command which could be used to set the font size to one that you desire in a key binding, but this only modifies the font size of the current view (while the commands above make the change permanent globally), so this is a non-solution.

A solution that doesn't require a plugin to modify the behaviour would be to remove the binding from the mouse wheel entirely, or alter it so that it requires a different modifier key. That way it won't trigger by accident at all.

In order to do that, you need to create or modify the file `Packages\User\Default.sublime-mousemap`. In order to determine where your `User` package is stored, you can use `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the menu.

Something like the following stored as the contents of that file will remove the binding completely, so that font changes with the mouse wheel are not possible. If the file already exists, just add the second and third lines to the file, making sure that all entries end in a comma.

```json
[
    { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "noop" },
    { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "noop" }
]
```

If you still want this functionality from the mouse, then you need a couple of extra lines to add the commands back. It's important that the two lines that map to the `noop` command remain; if you don't override them explicitly the defaults will remain.

Here's an example of requiring <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> to both be held during a mouse scroll to modify the font size.

```json
[
    { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "noop" },
    { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "noop" },

    { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["shift", "ctrl"], "command": "decrease_font_size" },
    { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["shift", "ctrl"], "command": "increase_font_size" }
]
```

Comment: I used the last set of commands and it works like charm Thank you so much ..!

Comment: @OdatNurd From what I read here about `set_setting` it seem there is no option to create a plugin which will set the font size to some specific, user-defined size? (pseudo-reset)

Comment: @jsv it's possible to do something like this with a plugin (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46823776/814803) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46790515/814803)). The answer here doesn't provide a plugin example because the OP mentioned having problems with them.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you very much, there are a lot of ST answers here by you and they are always very useful and thorough. By the way, what does `noop` mean here? Is it just a funny word which could be changed to anything non-existing like `foobarbaz`?

Comment: @jsv You need to specify something in the command field and Sublime doesn't generate errors for commands that don't exist, so as long as you use something that's not a known command it will work. `noop` is short for `no operation`, which is a programming term, so that's why I generally use that.

Answer (score 10):

Go to *Preference->Settings* and change the font size as you want....

Comment: At first I thought this answer had misread the question, but no, *changing the font size is **exactly** what ctrl-plus and ctrl-minus do in Sublime*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46823776/1028230) for even more on Sublime Text font size increase/decrease commands.

Comment: To reset the zoom using this answer, you should write `"font_size": 10`.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Preferences>keybinding

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+0",], "command": "reset_font_size" },
```

add this line at the last line before "]" in the right panel and save it.
Now every time you want to reset use this keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

However, there isn't a keyboard shortcut for resetting the zoom/font size. Normally this would be `super + 0`(aka `cmd + 0`) in most apps, but Sublime Text doesn't give you this by default.

To get this feature you need to add the following to your keyboard bindings (found under `Preferences -> Key Bindings`)

```
  { "keys": ["super+0"], "command": "reset_font_size" }
```

> Courtesy: coderwall.com

Answer (score 0):

For Apple or MacOS, Press the `Command Key -> ⌘)` with either `+` or `-` key to increase or decrease text size in sublime accordingly

Answer (score -2):

Press ctrl + to increase font and ctrl shift + to decrease font size.
I used and it works.

Comment: the question is to reset not make bigger or smaller, how would you know the original size to decrease to it or increase to it ?!